# How to initialize an Array of Sets of HashMaps

Tags: java

Hey there stackoverflow,

I've been trying to initialize an :
1. Array of
2. Sets of
3. HashMaps

Declaration seems to work

```
private static Set<HashMap<Integer,Integer>>[] mp;
```

But I'm struggling to initialize it. Please help me out :)

Comment: Arrays and generics don't mix well. Use a `List<Set<Map<Integer, Integer>>>` instead. Or better yet, use a proper class to model your data.

Comment: Thank you shmosel !! I will define a class holding the HashMaps and the Sets !